# Error installing Perforce plugin (P4WSAD) to Zend Studio 7

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio, perforce

I am running Zend Studio build 20090901

I am trying to install the Perforce plugin but I receive this error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
  session context was:(profile=studioProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde,3.4.100.v200909170800
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.api.tools,1.0.101.v20090714
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.ui,1.0.101.v20090820
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.build,3.5.1.R35x_20090820
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.core,3.5.100.v20090821
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.doc.user,3.5.0.v20090818
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.pde,3.5.1.R35x_v20090811-7Z7_F9zFDX-aT6Ywvh8_S93
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.runtime,3.4.100.v20090731
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.ui,3.5.0.v20090821
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.views.log,1.0.100.v20090731
```

I have searched the forums and can't seem to find anyone else with this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I posted this question, a couple new versions of Zend Studio have been released, which fixed this issue.

Installing P4WSAD now installs without issues.